# Building web app using scraping and if/else commands

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a web app, which should be fairly straightforward, but which is complicated by the fact I'm trying to include a scraping operation.

What I'm trying to achieve, is this:

The customer visits the website, and gets a text box where they enter their car's license plate number. This will then return a price for a specific repair.

I want to achieve this by adding the license plate number to the below URI (in this example, 1-KBB-00 is the license plate number).

```
https://www.finnik.nl/autorapport/1-KBB-00
```

This url returns a webpage with a large table listing all kinds of specifications belonging to this car. The one I'm looking for is:

```
 Aantal versnellingen
```

which in this example has a value of "5". On the website that belongs to the mentioned URI, this looks like:

```
<tr>
<th scope="row" class="col-sm-8">
          Aantal versnellingen
        </th>
<td>
5
</td>
</tr>
```

For virtually all cars, this value will be either 5 or 6. I want the script to scrape or get this value, and then apply an if/else command to display the price. In case the value is 5, the price is "X", if the value is 6, the price is "Y" and if the value is anything else than 5 or 6, the script will return an error message telling the customer to contact the company in order to get a quote.

Now I'm able to implement the if/else part of the script myself, and appending the license plate to the url shouldn't be an issue either, but I'm at a loss when it comes to scraping the data from this table.

I've optimistically tried to use a 'get' command, but unsurprisingly that didn't work. I've googled my eyes out, but I haven't been able to find a proper solution, and a part of me is wondering if this is even possible. However, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be, so any help is much appreciated!

NB: the website I'm working with is built on Wordpress, so any solution would have to be compatible with Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are a couple options in the form of WordPress plugins:

- [WP Web Scraper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-web-scrapper/)
- [Supra Scraper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/supra-scraper/)

If neither of these work you can put something together using PHP.

There are a couple of libraries:

- [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte)
- [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Lastly, another option would be to roll your own completely from scratch, going this route you could use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to retrieve the page. Once you have the HTML you could use [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to find the data you want.

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent answer. I'm going to look at all options and see what I'll do.